# Three Exponential Equations

Tags: exponential-function

Could any of you guys assist me with the following questions. Thanks. I first tried moving everything to one side, but don't know how to continue.

Solve the following algebraically:

Question 1: 
$$5^{2x+1} + 25 = 5^{x+3} + 5^x$$

Answer is:

$x= -1 ,2$

Question 2: 
$$8^x +7\times2^{x+1} = 7\times4^x+8$$

Answer is:

$x= 0,1 ,  2$

Question 3:
$$3^{3x} -12\times9^x + 63\times 3^x = 4\times3^3$$

Answer is:

$x=1$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: write your first equation as $$5\cdot (5^x)^2+25=125\cdot 5^x+5^x$$
and your second equation as $$(3^x)^3+14\cdot 2^x=7\cdot (2^x)^2+8$$
and the last one as
$$(3^x)^3-12\cdot (3^x)^2+63\cdot 3^x=4\cdot 3^3$$

Comment: In the first equation, where does the 125 come from?

Comment: $5^{x+3}=5^3 \cdot 5^x = 125 \cdot 5^x$

Comment: Oh ok thanks heaps

Comment: After writing the equations like that, what would be my next step

Comment: set for example $t=5^x$ and solve the equation in $t$

Comment: So, the equation would look like $5\times(y)^2+25= 125y + y$

Comment: and the right-hand side $$5y^2+25=125\cdot y+y$$

Comment: Yes sorry, was meant to be 125. Now I factorize the equation?

Comment: solve the quadratic equation $$5y^2-126y+25=0$$ for $y$

Comment: So, $5y^2-126y+25=0$

Comment: $(y-1)(y-125)$ right? 

So, $5^x=1$ and $5^x=125$

Comment: this is ok and you can solve your equation

Comment: So $x=0,3$ but the answer is supposed to be $x=-1,2$

Comment: the factorization is $$(5y-1)(y-25)=0$$

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake! Thanks heaps.

Comment: you are welcome and a nice Sunday

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

all these can be solved by substitution. In the first use $y=5^x$, in the second $y=2^x$ and do yourself for the last one.